# Microsoft Edge : How to scroll in a text field?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, cursor, microsoft-edge

How do I move the cursor of a text filed always to the end?

[image: pic]

This picture shows the current status.
I have to enter '1234123412341234'.
But I can only see '12341234123'.

What I want, 
Although the length of the text is longer than the length of the field, 
I will see the last typed character.
Because the text is that it will be scrolled.(The cursor will be to the right of the last typed character.)

I know how to do this work in other browsers.
But I do not know how to do this at the edge.

I want to scroll the text in a text field....!!!
Please help me :-(
Thank you.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue you're reporting; can you share more information? The version of Edge and Windows 10, along with a repro on http://jsfiddle.net, would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you any work on your script about text scroll? If you have a work, can you share script to me? My version of Edge is 20.10240.16384.0 and my version of Windows 10 is Home K. Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Can you record a GIF of the problem? You can use either [ScreenToGIF](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/) or [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).